# how to set android:host in BroadcastReceiver or Activity in android programmatically?

Tags: android

i am trying to add android:host="8097" in activity or broadcastReceiver programmatically but i didn't get any answer i searched lot..

```
<receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SECRET_CODE" />
            <data android:scheme="android_secret_code" android:host="8097"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

so i want to add android:host="8097" programmatically not in manifests..

Comment: You set it on the `IntentFilter` you register the Receiver with – [`IntentFilter#addDataAuthority()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#addDataAuthority(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: Thanks its work :)